# Nextjs: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js

I am trying to export a nextjs webapp to github pages but couldn't 'next export' .It says:Nextjs: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.
Possible solution says - Use the `loader` prop for `next/image`.
What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader):

"The next/image component's default loader uses the 'squoosh' library for image resizing and optimization. This library is quick to install and suitable for a dev server environment. For a production environment, it is strongly recommended that you install the optional sharp library by running `yarn add sharp` in your project directory."

see if this helps